When I open the Go file in NVIM, an error message appears
problem in nvim for go files the error massage:
Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/inlay_hint.lua:408: enable: expected boolean, got number
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        vim/shared.lua: in function 'validate'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/inlay_hint.lua:408: in function 'enable'
        ...e/yossef/.local/share/nvim/lazy/go.nvim/lua/go/inlay.lua:322: in function ''
        vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0>
Press ENTER or type command to continue



the distro:
Distributor ID: Arch
Description:    Arch Linux
Release:        rolling
Codename:       n/a
nvim version:
NVIM v0.10.0
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1713773202
Run "nvim -V1 -v" for more info
so how slove the problem and fix the error

the problem use in the plugin go.nvim

I had the same issue..my fix: In on_attach function of gopls:
                    on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
                        if client.supports_method("textDocument/inlayHint") then
                            vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(true, {
                                assignVariableTypes = true,
                                compositeLiteralFields = true,
                                compositeLiteralTypes = true,
                                constantValues = true,
                                functionTypeParameters = true,
                                parameterNames = true,
                                rangeVariableTypes = true,
                            })
                        end
                    end,

probably in vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable arguments are not passed correctly.
